# Best way to combine lists netcdf into one dataframe in R - Nested for loops or mapply?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dplyr, mapply

I am trying to combine multiple netcdf files with multiple variables:

```
- 6 types of parameters
-36 years
- 12 months
-31 days
- 6 Y coordinates
- 5 X coordinates
```

Each netcdf file contains data for 1 month of a year and 1 parameter, there are thus 432 * 6 =2592 files.

How would I best combine this all in a dataframe? It would in the end have to generate something like this:

```
rowID   Date        year  month day coord.X coord.Y par1 par2  par3  par4 par5  par6       
1       1979-01-01  1979  01    01  176     428     3.2  0.005 233.5 0.1  12.2  4.4
..................... 402568 rows in between.................
402570  2014-12-31  2014  12    31  180     433     1.7  0.006 235.7 0.2  0.0   2.7
```

How would I best combine this? I already have been struggling with this quite some time...

*Excuse me for not knowing how to be able to make this question reproducible..* but there are so many elements involved.
This where I have my files from:
ftp://rfdata:forceDATA@ftp.iiasa.ac.at/WFDEI/

**This is what I have so far**, I think this what they call a nested loop right?:
I ussually just try and try and try and in the end it works.. but I find this a tough job. Any recommendations on first steps are welcome, please.

```
require(ncdf4)
directory<-c("C:/folder/")                              # general folder
parameter<-c("par1","par2","par3","par4","par5","par6") # names of 6 parameters
directory2<-c("_folder2/")                              # parameter specific folder
directory3<-c("name")                                   # last part of folder name
years<-c("1979","otheryears","2014")                    # years which are also part of netcdf file name
months<-c("01","othermonths","12")                      # months which are also part of netcdf file name
x=c(176:180)                                            # X-coordinates
y=c(428:433)                                            # Y-coordinates



 require(plyr)

 for (p in parameter){
assign(paste0(p,"list"), list())
  for (i in years){
   for (j in months){
    for (k in x){
      for (l in y){
fileloc<-paste(directory,p,directory2,p,directory3,i,j,".nc",sep="") #location to open
    ncin<-nc_open(fileloc)
assign(paste0(p))<-ncvar_get(ncin,p)                         # extract the desired parameter from the netcdf list "ncin" and store in vector with name of parameter
day<-ncvar_get(ncin,"day")                                   # extract the day of month from the netcdf list "ncin"
par.coord<-paste(p,"[",y,",",x,",","]",sep="")               #string with function to select coordinates
temp<-data.frame(i,j,day,p=par.coord)                        # store day and parameter in dataframe
temp<-cbind(date=as.Date(with(temp,paste(i,j,day,sep="-")),"%Y-%m-%d"),temp,Y=y,X=x)                                               # Add date and coordinates to df
assign(paste0(p,"list"), list(temp)                          #store multiple data frames in a list.. I think?
    }assign(paste0(p,"list"), do.call(rbind,data)            # something to bind the dataframes by row in a list
}}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to extract these Netcdf files by extract and group all the Netcdf files in one dataframe by:

```
-6 parameters
-36 years
-12 months
-31 days
-6 Y coordinates
-5 X coordinates
```

First I made sure all *.nc files were in one folder.
Second I simplified multiple for loops into one, since variables as year, month and parameter were available from the file name:

The variables day, Xcoord and Y coord could be extracted as one in an array.

```
require(arrayhelpers);require(stringr);require(plyr);require(ncdf4)
# store all files from ftp://rfdata:forceDATA@ftp.iiasa.ac.at/WFDEI/ in the following folder:
setwd("C:/folder")
temp = list.files(pattern="*.nc")           #list all the file names
param<-gsub("_\\S+","",temp,perl=T)         #extract parameter from file name

xcoord=seq(176,180,by=1)                    #The X-coordinates you are interested in
ycoord=seq(428,433,by=1)                    #The Y-coordinates you are interested in

list_var<-list()                         # make an empty list
for (t in 1:length(temp)){
temp_year<-str_sub(temp[],-9,-6)                                                                                #take string number last place minus 9 till last place minus 6 to extract the year from file name
temp_month<-str_sub(temp[],-5,-4)                                                                               #take string number last place minus 9 till last place minus 6 to extract the month from file name
temp_netcdf<-nc_open(temp[t]) 
temp_day<-rep(seq(1:length(ncvar_get(temp_netcdf,"day"))),length(xcoord)*length(ycoord))                   # make a string of day numbers the same length as amount of values
dim.order<-sapply(temp_netcdf[["var"]][[param[t]]][["dim"]],function(x) x$name)                            # gives the name of each level of the array
start <- c(lon = 428, lat = 176, tstep = 1)                                                                     # indicates the starting value of each variable
count <- c(lon = 6, lat = 5, tstep = length(ncvar_get(nc_open(temp[t]),"day")))                                 # indicates how many values of each variable have to be present starting from start
tempstore<-ncvar_get(temp_netcdf, param[t], start = start[dim.order], count = count[dim.order])            # array with parameter values

df_temp<-array2df (tempstore, levels = list(lon=ycoord, lat = xcoord, day = NA), label.x = "value")           # convert array to dataframe
Add_date<-sort(as.Date(paste(temp_year[t],"-",temp_month[t],"-",temp_day,sep=""),"%Y-%m-%d"),decreasing=FALSE)  # make vector with the dates
list_var[t]<-list(data.frame(Add_date,df_temp,parameter=param[t]))                                         #add dates to data frame and store in a list of all output files
  nc_close(temp_netcdf)                                                                                           #close nc file to prevent data loss and prevent error when working with a lot of files
}
All_NetCDF_var_in1df<-do.call(rbind,list_var)  

#### If you want to take a look at the netcdf files first use:
list2env(
  lapply(setNames(temp, make.names(gsub("*.nc$", "", temp))), 
         nc_open), envir = .GlobalEnv) #import all parameters lists to global environment
```

Answer (score 1):

There are *many* ways to skin a cat like that.  Nested loops are perhaps a bit easier to debug if you're new with R.  One question I think you want to ask yourself is whether the files have primacy or your conceptual structure has primacy. That is, if your conceptual structure specifies a location for which there isn't a file, what do you want your code to do?  If you only want to try to parse extant files, I find it useful to use a `list.files(, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)` to find the files I want to parse and then write a function to parse a single file (and its name) to produce the data structure I want.  From there, it is an `lapply` or `purrr::map`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am indeed new to R and programming and have only worked with non-nested for loops once before.
I have never heard of  purrr::map, perhaps its ineed better to just list the files per parameter because I indeed want to parse extant files. 
If lapply doesn't work for me I will try purrr::map